# Magento 1.9: Observer not working. Is there any way to test observer is working or not?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have added below code in my `config.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<global>
      <events>
            <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
                <observers>
                    <oroola_oroolachildren_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>oroola_oroolachildren/observer</class>
                        <method>updateProductPrice</method>
                    </oroola_oroolachildren_observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

So as per above configuration file, I have created a Observer.php file in app/code/local/Oroola/Oroolachildren/Model/

Observer.php

```
<?php
Class Oroola_Oroolachildren_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function updateProductPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
    {
        header('Location: http://www.google.com/');
        die();
        $quote = $obs->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        $product_id=$item->getProductId();
        $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $newprice=$_product->getPrice()+rand(10,100);

        Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');

        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($newprice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newprice);
        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        die();
    }
}

?>
```

I have added php header and redirect it to google.com to test its working or not.

But This is not working.

I want to change Product price before/after add to cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed code in config.xml file and after clear cache it is working.

```
<class>Oroola_Oroolachildren_Model_Observer</class>
<method>updateProductPrice</method>
```